# WP7 - just few controls when silverlight toolkit added

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, visual-studio-2012, silverlight-toolkit

I am trying to add Silverlight Toolkit to my Windows Phone 7.1 application but when I added `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit` reference I got just few controls in Intellisense (like `ContextMenuService, DatePickerPage, GestureService`, ...). Nothing like `ToggleSwitch` and other controls. I tried to add reference several ways (from Program Files, via Nuget, other project) and always the same. I tried to se reference in Object browser and controls are there. Ofcourse I added namespace to xaml page:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

So where is problem? Thanks

Comment: You mean the Windows Phone Toolkit, right?
https://nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit

Comment: Yea, I think WPtoolkit separates from Silverlight toolkit because "manage  Windows Phone specific codebase and issues." So exactly I mean WPtoolkit and that's what I tried but I think describe it as Silverlight toolkit is allright too.

Comment: Yep, you're fine.  Just checking to be sure you weren't trying to install a nuget package for the wrong platform